# FontAwesome not loading on deployed Netlify website

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have recently hosted a Netlify website. On my machine (2021 M1 Mac on PyCharm local-host), one of the pages contains a grid as such:

[image]

However, when I host it on netlify, the icons seem to lose dimension as if the link I am using was not working.

Link: `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c4254e24a8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Weblink: https://makerscience.netlify.app/services

Hosted image:

[image]

I've tried to see if a different kit link would work but this does not seem to be the case.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console or network tab of the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that your netlify domain is added to the allowed domains that have permission to use your fontawesome script.

I copied your script tag and tried it out locally to see if it has domains set to "open", and nothing loads for me(this is a good thing cuz we don't want everyone to be able to use your kit). So my guess is you have limited domains set to access the styles. I would keep it like that, and then just add the netlify domains to the permissions in the fontawesome kit settings.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely was the issue.